# Pack/Import a local developed module into a project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-module, ng-packagr

I am trying to import a locally developed Angular project/module into an angular application without publishing it into npm repository.

First, I followed this tutorial to build my module in UMD format (I skipped the publish part):

> https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464

Then, I tried to install my module in the final application by executing this command line:

```
npm install ../path-to-my-module --save
```

This added successfully my module as `@myscope/myModule` in the `package.json` of my application, but the problem is that the import of the module in the application isn't recognized. I ended up by getting the following error:

```
Cannot find module @myscope/myModule
```

In my `node_modules`, the folder `@myscope` is created, and inside it, there is a shortcut to `../path-to-my-module` with the name `myModule`

Could the fact that there is a shortcut be the source of the problem? and if so how to fix it?

Comment: It adds the package to your `package.json`, but it's most likely not installing the module into your node_modules.

Comment: In my `node_modules`, the folder `@myscope/myModule` is created, and inside it, there is a link to `../path-to-my-module`. I will add this information into my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this article that helped me to solve my problem:

> https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

---

To give a brief summary, this is how I proceeded:

1. Install **ng-packagr**:

   - Install it globally:
     `npm install -g ng-packagr`
   - Install it in the project module:
     `npm install ng-packagr --save-dev`
2. create `ng-package.json` in the root folder of the project, and add the following:

   ```html
   {
     "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
     "lib": {
       "entryFile": "public_api.ts"   
       "externals": {
         "@angular/cdk": "ng.cdk",
         "@angular/cdk/accordion": "ng.cdk.accordion",
          //...
       }
     }
   }
   ```

In my case I had to add external dependencies in order to avoid packaging/build errors:

3. create `public_api.ts` in the root folder of the project, and add the following:

   `export * from './src/app/modules/myFeature/my-feature.module'`
4. Edit `package.json`, and add the `packagr` line to the `scripts` tag:

```html
"scripts": {
  //...
  "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
}
```

5. Create the package by running the following command from the root folder:

   `npm run packagr`
6. Install it for local development:

   - Pack the module by running the following command from the `dist` folder:
     `npm pack`
   - Install the packed module from the final project:
     `npm install ../some-relative-path/dist/my-component-library-0.0.0.tgz`

Then I could import my module from any other module or component of my final project

Comment: Hi, I managed to do the same. My question is how do you continuously build the component library without have to re-build it each time you want to see a change in your project that is actually consuming the component library?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a direct way that allows to reflect the change that is made in the component library directly in the final project that uses it. Maybe automating a script can do the job? Like for example: 1. Build the library `npm run packagr` 2. Package it `npm pack` 3. Install it `npm install ../some-relative-path/dist/my-component-library-0.0.0.tgz`

Comment: After doing some digging I found some examples that are supposed to do a reload whenever one of the files in the library project change. Take a look here. So far I have tried it and I have not gotten the results they are mentioning. https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library#how-can-i-avoid-recompilation-during-development . The other thing I see is that there was a ticket in relation to not being able to recompile the ts files inside lib project. https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/72. This example is with yeoman and I did switch over to try.

Comment: instead of `npm pack`, can we use `npm link`?

Comment: @TerNovi With Angular CLI 6.2 there is a way to build a library in `--watch` mode: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library#why-do-i-need-to-build-the-library-everytime-i-make-changes