# ng build cannot find module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to locally test 3 node modules by updating the locations they are being pulled from in their `package.json` files.  The modules are `sdk`, `ng-widget-lib`, and `frontend`.  `ng-widget-lib` depends on `sdk` and `frontend` depends on `ng-widget-lib`.  I build `sdk` locally with `babel`. I'm running verdaccio as a local npm registry.

I update `ng-widget/package.json` (the name of the repo/root directory is `ng-widget` not `ng-widget-lib`) changing the name to `@locals/ng-widget-lib` and point the `sdk` dependency to the local `sdk` directory. Then run npm install and build with `ng build` which runs successfully.  I then change the name in `dist/package.json` to `@locals/ng-widget-lib` and publish to my local registry.

In `frontend/package.json` I point the `ng-widget-lib` dependency to `@locals/ng-widget-lib` (I have tried pointing it to the local directory and not using the local registry but this still doesn't work).  I run `npm install` which downloads the module from my local registry to `node_modules/@locals/ng-widget-lib` and creates a `package-lock.json` with `ng-widget-lib` pointing to the local registry.  Then when I run `ng build --prod` or `ng build` it fails in the files where I'm importing `@locals/ng-widget-lib` with error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@locals/ng-widget-lib'.

I have deleted `node_modules` and run `npm cache clean --force` but still the same error.  The `ng-widget-lib` and `frontend` use angular 8, `sdk` is typescript.  I'm using npm 6.11.3

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48150290/3614578 and was able to import the local module successfully.  I put the `ngPackage` config directly in `package.json`, and I also didn't have to run `npm pack`.  This is my config in `package.json`

```
"ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "./projects/ng-widget-lib/src/public_api.ts"
    },
    "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
      "angular",
      "rxjs",
      "tslib",
      "zone.js"
    ]
  }
```

I was also able to get it to build after installing from my local registry.  I followed this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library.  Basically there is a special command for building angular libraries that needs to be run `ng generate library my-lib`, and then you have to publish from your `dist/<lib-name>` folder, not your root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try with compiler option preserveSymlinks.

All local modules has to be used as preserveSymlinks in compiler options

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "preserveSymlinks": true
```

Read More:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Didn't work, its actually downloading the module from http://localhost:4873/ into my `node_modules` directory so I don't think its using a sym link

Comment: u didn't mentioned that. Once require start in start of the app, all caching done. you cant modify the require async. require is block and sync. In node js dynamic require is not possible, the only web u can do the dynamic import. using tools like webpack, system.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Adding one file `index.ts` as a sibling(next to) `package.json` worked like a charm.

- Export everything from `public_api.ts` using `index.ts` only
- Replace the `entryFile` location from `public_api.ts` to `index.ts`

> Content inside `index.ts` as follows:

```
export * from './src/public_api.ts';
```

> So the content would like for `ng-packgr` as follows:

```
"ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "index.ts"
    },
  }
```