# Angular directive required to implement GoogleSigninButtonDirective in @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.5 does not work for Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

Although the library states that [@abacritt/angularx-social-login:1 is compatible with Angular 13 and 14](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login#compatibility-matrix), it is not working for my Angular 13 project, this error is thrown after `npm start`, which seems to blame `GoogleSigninButtonDirective` for the error, and the reason being that it requires Angular 14:

```
./node_modules/@abacritt/angularx-social-login/fesm2015/abacritt-angularx-social-login.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):    
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\@abacritt\angularx-social-login\fesm2015\abacritt-angularx-social-login.mjs: This application 
depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.2.0, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
  457 | }
  458 | GoogleSigninButtonDirective.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.2.0", ngImport: i0, type: GoogleSigninButtonDirective, deps: [{ token: i0.ElementRef }, { token: SocialAuthService }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive });
> 459 | GoogleSigninButtonDirective.ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "14.2.0", type: GoogleSigninButtonDirective, selector: "asl-google-signin-button", inputs: { type: "type", size: "size", text: "text", shape: "shape", theme: "theme", logo_alignment: "logo_alignment", width: "width", locale: "locale"9m }, ngImport: i0 });
      |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^[1m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^[1m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^[1m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  460 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.2.0", ngImport: i0, type: GoogleSigninButtonDirective, decorators: [{
  461 |             type: Directive,
  462 |             args: [{'
    at run (C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
    at C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
    at C:\Vidoqui\Repositories\vidoqui-frontend2\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40

Error: node_modules/@abacritt/angularx-social-login/directives/google-signin-button.directive.d.ts:15:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s).

15     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<GoogleSigninButtonDirective, "asl-google-signin-button", never, { "type": "type"; "size": "size"; "text": "text"; "shape": "shape"; "theme": "theme"; "logo_alignment": "logo_alignment"; "width": "width"; "locale": "locale"; }, {}, never, never, false>;
```

A little more of context, I followed the documentation to install @abacritt/angularx-social-login:1, which requires the following:

1. Adding the dependency with `npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login`
2. In `AppModule`, import the `SocialLoginModule` and add providers (in my case I just need the `GoogleLoginProvider`)
3. Use `<asl-google-signin-button type='icon' size='medium'></asl-google-signin-button>` in the component template/html where I want the google button to show

Snippet of my `AppModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'clientId'
            )
          }
        ],
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

Snippet of my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@abacritt/angularx-social-login": "^1.2.5",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.11",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have tried to install the dependency adding the `--legacy-peers-dep` flag, as stated in this [github issue comment](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/599#issuecomment-1301123555) (Although it seems to be a solution for `angularx-social-login:4` and NOT for `@abacritt/angularx-social-login:1`, which is newer). That is, using `npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login --legacy-peer-deps`, but it is still not working.

I also tried to use version 1.1 instead of 1.2. Because 1.1 was made before adding support for Angular 14. This version (1.1) do work. The installation is different though. And the problem is it seems to be communicating with Google in a way that will be deprecated in March 31, 2023, so is not a very solid solution

Comment: It does not seem possible, see https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/602. The compatibly matrix is outdated.

Comment: How about updating to Angular 14?

Comment: @MikeFeustel I ended up updating to Angular 14, so that solved the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what the outdated documentation says, the last version of the library that works with Angular 13 was version `1.2.3`. In version `1.2.4`, they start building using `Angular 14.2.0`, dropping backwards compatibility for Angular 13. (See: [the commit the caused the problem](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/commit/6820f8a06f24712cb36b658d212e029f74904aa6), and [the stale bug about it](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/602).)

It seems you have three choices:

1. Use version `1.2.3` of the plugin, which is the final version that supports Angular 13. You can install it via `npm install @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.3 --save`
2. Upgrade your project to Angular 14.
3. Use a different plugin.

Comment: In the docs, they stated that the latest library will also support Angular 13 as well, which is not valid anymore and is kinda confusing.

Comment: @MaidenlessRunt About 2 days ago they made a commit [upgrading it to Angular 15](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/commit/83e2b8feb15c80fb5135b6a9b06164e44cdffd57)(!). It might be more worthwhile to upgrade your project to Angular 15 and wait a few weeks for it to get released.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll have to build the library for Angular 13 yourself. Similar to what is described here: [Pack/Import a local developed module into a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106093/pack-import-a-local-developed-module-into-a-project)

I've adapted the project [here](https://github.com/Mike-F362/vidoqui-frontend2-ng13.git), with the library as a sub-repo. I checked in the built library under `lib/abacritt-angularx-social-login-1.2.5.tgz` to let the installation finish without building the sub-repo. In the angularx-social-login submodule I've created a `ng13` branch with downgraded Angular dependencies.

Unfortunately, I was able to wrest version and sub-repo handling from StackBlitz on the fly, so you have to look at the fork at [GitHub](https://github.com/Mike-F362/angularx-social-login.git)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this bug by running the following command if you have imported all the mentioned modules:-
npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.3 --save OR

npm i @abacritt/angularx-social-login@1.2.3 --legacy-peer-deps

& it runs in both Angular 15 and 16